# Android relative layout and different screen sizes/devices

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout, screen-size

I just wrote all this and I'm being told by this little red bar that I can't post pictures, or more than two links. So if you could kindly reference [this Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ2kg.jpg), that'd be great. Thank you.

I'm relatively new here and even newer to android programming. I am trying to write an app that emphasizes visual appeal more than functional appeal. It's not an assignment or work related, it's just something I wanna try out.

So I've hit a roadblock. I am wrangling with the layout of some `TextView` boxes when in different emulators and devices. I have been reading [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) but it's kind of long and it doesn't seem to solve my problem and honestly, it's just over my head.

So here's my issue.

I have some `TextView` boxes and I used the `layout` attributes in XML, and in the Design window with a Nexus 4 mock device in Android studio, it looks like this (Image 1)

The code looks like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/anger"
    android:id="@+id/angertv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/happiness"
    android:id="@+id/happinesstv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="34dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/fear"
    android:id="@+id/feartv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sadness"
    android:id="@+id/sadnesstv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="66dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/surprise"
    android:id="@+id/surprisetv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/disgust"
    android:id="@+id/disgusttv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="74dp" />
```

I have been using the parent borders to position the 6 words on the devices screen. But when time comes to run it, it looks like this (Image 2) on a Nexus 5 emulator screen, and when on an actual HTC One m8, it looks like  this (Image 3).

So I try something like this instead:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/anger"
    android:id="@+id/angertv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/center"
    android:layout_marginStart="70dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/happiness"
    android:id="@+id/happinesstv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="67dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/fear"
    android:id="@+id/feartv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_above="@+id/center"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sadness"
    android:id="@+id/sadnesstv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/center"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/surprise"
    android:id="@+id/surprisetv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_above="@+id/center"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/disgust"
    android:id="@+id/disgusttv"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/center"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
```

I use an extra `TextView` (ID'd `center`) which is aligned to the center of the device, which is empty and use it to align it the other Views with text in them. These are the results.

Design window Nexus 4: (Image 4)

Nexus 5 emulator: (Image 5)

HTC One m8: (Image 6)

It's better but not quite. Ideally, the words should stay in one place inside the pie slices I have made. I have been looking around but nothing seems specific, and since I'm a beginner at all this, I can't seem to extrapolate from peoples answers to other questions that are maybe similar but not quite like this situation.

If anyone could explain to me how I can solve this issue, or point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Is the pie and image?

Comment: Another possible work around would be to create a shapedrawable in an xml and use that as the background for your word

Comment: If you want it to cater to all devices then you shouldn't be using absolute positioning values i.e. `marginTop="68dp"` as they will change depending on the screen size and resolution of the device. Have you tried to have a crack at this without using absolute sizes?

Comment: No, the pie is a bunch of `VectorDrawable` paths in an `ImageView` under the `TextView`s

Comment: I'm sorry blueprintChris. I have no idea what absolute sizes are and what the opposite of that is :(

Comment: Have you noticed that the 'Happy' and 'Anger' TextViews are fine no matter what device/screen you're using, but the rest look messed up? I would put my money on it being to do with the fact that you've put `marginTop` and `marginBottom` on your TextViews. `dp` is a measurement based on the resolution of the screen. The higher the resolution, the more dpi (dots per inch) the screen has, which makes this value slightly different on every screen. Try using a different approach instead of `marginTop=xxdp` and `marginBottom=xxdp`

Comment: @blueprintChris Yes. I have tried to use the attributes that don't require an absolute value where possible. Which is why I have used `layout_centerVertical` for the Happy and Angry TextViews. The rationale behind the empty TextView in the second attempt was to see if it would work better if I aligned things to the center of the screen. But I guess that still uses absolute margins. Are there any non-absolute attributes I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@dimen` different dimen files so that different screen sizes will have different font sizes.

```
android:textSize="@dimen/text_28"
```

Have the dimen values in different directories:

res/values/dimen.xml

```
<dimen name="text_28">28sp</dimen>
```

res/values-600dp/dimen.xml

```
<dimen name="text_28">22sp</dimen>
```

etc.

You'll have to play around with different font sizes and screen sizes but you should be able to find something that works.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSizeQuali

And this page shows some popular device metrics:
https://design.google.com/devices/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cory. After some consideration, I think I'm going to change these titles into SVG paths and set them. After all, these titles are more visually motivated and aren't really functional. I'll definitely try this if that doesn't work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome.  The SVG or custom view will likely work even better. Good luck!